# AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys

I have a table defined as

```
class Results(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'results'
    event_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Events.id), primary_key=True)
    event = db.relationship('Events', foreign_keys='Results.event_id')
    team_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Teams.id), primary_key=True)
    team = db.relationship('Teams', foreign_keys='Results.team_id')
    position = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)
    rr_position = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)
    score = db.Column(db.Float, default=0)
```

and

```
class Teams(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'teams'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
    country = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
```

When I run the following

```
r = Results.query.all()
print(len(r))
```

I get 138 rows.

If I run

```
r =  db.session.query(Teams.name
    , Results.team_id
    , Results.event_id).all()
print(len(r))
```

or

```
r = Results.query.add_column(Teams.name).all()
print(len(r))
```

then I get 6072 rows. With this query, I am expecting 138 rows and one team name for each.

But if I try

```
r ==  db.session.query(Results.team.name
    , Results.team_id
    , Results.event_id).all()
```

I get the following error

AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Results.team has an attribute 'name'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried explicitly specifying the join when performing the query?

For example:

```
db.session.query(Results.team_id, Results.event_id, Team.name).join(Team).all()
```

I am assuming in the case where > 6000 entries are returned, you are getting the cartesian result.

Comment: Thank you, that works.  Under what condistions can the relationship be used and when can it not?

Comment: If you want the intersection between two tables based off a field, you will want to explicitly specify the join. In this case, you are looking for an inner join.