# Flask/SQLAlchemy - query relationship AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with has an attribute

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

This works fine

```
protocols = db.session.query(Protocol.id, Protocol.customer_id).all()
```

results in

```
[(1, 1), (2, 1)]
```

If I try to include relationship column (`Protokol.zakaznik.objednatel`) instead of `Protocol.customer_id` in query it returns: `AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Protocol.zakaznik has an attribute 'objednatel'`.

```
protocols = db.session.query(Protocol.id, Protocol.zakaznik.objednatel).all()
```

If I iterate through protocols, the relationship works well

```
protocols = db.session.query(Protocol).all()
for protocol in protocols:
    print(protocol.zakaznik.objednatel)
    print(protocol.zakaznik.id)
```

So what is the problem in using relationship in query? Is it possible to return `[(1, CustomerObjednatel1), (2, CustomerObjednatel1)]`? I can of course do join query which works fine. I thought that using relationship would be shorter way of doing this.

models.py

```
class Customer(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    objednatel = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    protocols = db.relationship('Protocol', back_populates='zakaznik')
    

class Protocol(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    customer_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('customer.id'), nullable=False)
    zakaznik =  db.relationship('Customer', back_populates='protocols')
```

Answer (score 0):

don't define the models like that you can set backref in Protocol model, refer to [docs](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/)

```
class Customer(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
objednatel = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
protocols = db.relationship('Protocol',backref="cus")


class Protocol(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    customer_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('customer.id'), nullable=False)
```

You can make a query like that

```
customer1 = Customer.query.filter_by(id=1).first()
customer1.protocols[0].id // gives the id of the first protocol of customer1
```

Querying protocols, You can use the backref with `cus` to access the whole object Customer

```
protocol2 = Protocol.query.filter_by(id=2).first()
protocol2.cus // gives the full information of object something like - <Customer 2>
protocol2.cus.objednatel  // gives the objednatel of protocol2's customer
```

You can watch the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juPQ04_twtA) for more understanding

Comment: From what I've read I think that back_populates and backref are equivalents (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39869793/when-do-i-need-to-use-sqlalchemy-back-populates)). But yes, the way how you wrote the queries - this works. Sorry for being slow to understand but can you explain why I always need to filter by specific customer to access cus relationship? Why I can't query all protocols with cus relationships? It is because the way how the relationship "column" works?

Comment: ya you can query all the protocols like this `p = Protocol.query.filter_by().all()` , this gives a list of objects, loop through them like for i in p: print(p.cus , p.objednatel) .

Comment: OK, it also works without filter_by(), just `Protocol.query.all()`, but this will return `[<Protocol 1>, <Protocol 2>] ` when I write `db.session.query(Protocol.id, Protocol.customer_id).all() ` then this will return `[(1, 1), (2, 1)] ` but back to the original question why this will not work `db.session.query(Protocol.id, Protocol.cus.objednatel).all() `

Comment: I never queried like that maybe this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40020388/flask-sqlalchemy-db-session-querymodel-vs-model-query), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39193039/attributeerror-neither-instrumentedattribute-object-nor-comparator-object-a) can help.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found pretty much same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65480238/why-am-i-unable-to-generate-a-query-using-relationships) on SO.

From the answer there it looks like the `session.query` can't take relationship as an argument. They link [docs reference](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html), where it is written that entities are coming as argument. So I guess that relationship is not entity (entity's attribute) and session.query can't consume it. If somebody can confirm, it would be nice, but I guess this is it.